# Detecting memory leaks in the new AS profiler?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

So I am trying to wrap my head around memory leaks in android and I am having a hard time understanding how it works. I understand the logic behind the memory leaks but when I try to play with it in android studio 3.0 profiler it gets weird.

For example: I assign activity to a static variable in oncreate and leave it there, then rotate the device 3 times. This should cause a memory leak but AS profiler show this.

[image]

I am not sure on how to interpret this but

**1)** why does only 1 activity instance has a depth and others don't? After experimenting a little I figured out that if the instance has depth can not be garbage collected or am I wrong? Also when I initiate GC nothing changes for the first time and no activities gets GC'd and only after the second GC 2 other activities are gone.

**2)** So why no luck for the first time (same behaviour with normal activity without leaks) and how on earth did they get garbage collected if there is a reference to a static variable?

Comment: A `static` field can only point to one object at a time. So, if you have something like `static Activity foo`, `foo` is pointing to one `Activity`, not three. If you assign three values to `foo`, it will only point to the last one. The other two `Activity` instances could be garbage-collected, if nothing else refers to them.

Comment: Ok I get it. And what about the depth. Is it dafe to say that activity will be gc'd eventually if it has no depth?

Comment: I am not certain about what is going on there. It used to be that a heap dump only dumped objects with actual references, so any uncollected garbage would not be in the dump. Perhaps they changed that somewhere along the line.

Comment: @ArnisShaykh Were you ever able to confirm that no depth means it can be GC'd? I am seeing multiple instances of the same activity with no depth after screen rotations as well.

Comment: @Nathan yeah, no depth means it has no connection to the root and can be GC’d.